# jest test always failing on import './environment/validate';

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

need help on this if anyone encountered this maybe you can share your solution thanks.

so every time i test my component i always see this error, 
Im not sure what part i did wrong on this can anyone help me on this.

```
Test suite failed to run

/project/node_modules/expo/src/Expo.js:2
import './environment/validate';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

i tried adding ignore transformIgnorePatterns by adding (jest-)?

still not working

your help is greatly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 0):

What is the transformIgnorePattern that you used? It should look something like this:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!(expo)/)"
]
```

Comment: here is my transformIgnorePatterns pattern

"node_modules/(?!react-native|native-base-shoutem-theme|@shoutem/animation|@shoutem/ui|tcomb-form-native)"

i tried replacing it with what you send this gives me 3 more error
i use this ignore the connect error from using native-base

Comment: @correctify Alright, maybe you need all of that stuff. Just add `|expo` into your `transformIgnorePatterns` and try it again?

Comment: Hi @Anthony Morris thanks for the help yes it works thank you